# Can't get JSLink to work on external list

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-list, jslink

We have an external list surfacing data from a homegrown data source and I need to modify some of the values using JSLink (formatting dates, color-coding based on values, etc.)  I have a web part displaying the desired columns.  However, when I add set the JSLink path in the web part, it does not even load the script, much less transform the cell contents.  I've tested the same script on an ootb document library web part and it seems to work fine.

Can this even be done for an external list?  If so, where might I have gone wrong?

I've been tinkering in SP2013 but this really needs to work in SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this a while back.  We did not spend too much time to track it down and I can't find a reference that explicitly states it's not supported.  What we ended up doing was the old school JavaScript in a script webpart to create our modifications on page load.

Comment: That's my fallback, but it means that the list (or the associated web parts) can't load or refresh using ajax - which rather dramatically increases page load time.

Answer (score -1):

These post describe how to link JS Links with external lists. 
Have a look.

http://jsuhail.blogspot.com/2014/09/client-side-rendering-using-jslink-post.html

http://jsuhail.blogspot.com/2014/09/client-side-rendering-using-jslink-post_11.html

Comment: Please post the important parts from the post in your answer, as link only answers will not be useful if the link is broken.

Comment: The first link is just how to use JSlink, which is already pretty clear to me.  The second link doesn't seem to contain an answer the question at all. Is there something specific you're trying to point out?

Comment: What I guess is, you have to link your JS file with a external list right?